# An error about my asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem from my Asp.net MVC Blog website project.

[image]

I am filling textbox on admin website from this picture 
but website any operation so its can't operation on database.
I sent you project code about my website project error.

```
public class AdminMakaleController : Controller
{
    blogDB db = new blogDB();

    // GET: AdminMakale
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var makales = db.Makales.ToList();

        return View(makales);
    }

    // GET: AdminMakale/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: AdminMakale/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.KategoriId = new SelectList(db.Kategoris, "KategoriId", "KategoriAdi");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: AdminMakale/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Makale makale,string etiketler,HttpPostedFileBase Foto)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Makales.Add(makale);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you forgot to tell what is the error or exception and on which line it is coming

Comment: Can you explain it little more?

Comment: My problems; No error.only can't write on database